# How can I get a regular gcc etc. under HomeBrew under Mac OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx, gcc, compiler, llvm

I have a Mac with command-line developer tools installed, including Apple's LLVM C compiler, present as /bin/gcc.

How can I get a real gcc installed so that e.g. make will see the standard gcc instead of the LLVM compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple has bundled it's own version of `gcc`/`llvm`, you need to enable `homebrew/versions` repo before you can install different version of GCC.

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc48
```

Replace gcc48 with the version of gcc you want.

See also https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers